# Is there some way to add meta-data to JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I would like to add key-value pairs of metadata to arbitrary JavaScript objects. This metadata should not affect code that is not aware of the metadata, that means for example

```
JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(obj.WithMetaData('key', 'value'))
```

MetaData aware code should be able to retrieve the data by key, i.e.

```
obj.WithMetaData('key', 'value').GetMetaData('key') === 'value'
```

Is there any way to do it - in node.js? If so, does it work with builtin types such as `String` <strike>and even `Number`</strike>? (**Edit** Thinking about it, I don't care about real *primitives* like numbers, but having that for *string* instances would be nice).

Some Background: What I'm trying to do is cache values that are derived from an object with the object itself, so that

- to meta data unaware code, the meta data enriched object will look the same as the original object w/o meta
- code that needs the derived values can get it out of the meta-data if already cached
- the cache will get garbage collected alongside the object

Another way would be to store a hash table with the caches somewhere, but you'd never know when the object gets garbage collected. Every object instance would have to be taken care of manually, so that the caches don't leak.

(btw clojure has this feature: http://clojure.org/metadata)

Comment: This sounds like the `jQuery.data()` functionality to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ECMA5's new object properties API to store properties on objects that will not show up in enumeration but are nonetheless retrievable.

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.real_property = 'hello';
Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'meta_property', {value: 'some meta value'});
for (var i in myObj)
    alert(i+' = '+myObj[i]); //only one property - @real_property
alert(myObj.meta_property); //"some meta value"
```

More information here: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209074803/http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Feb/ECMAScript-revolution-object-properties-201)

However you're not going to be able to do this on primitive types such as strings or numbers, only on complex types.

[EDIT]

Another approach might be to utilise a data type's prototype to store meta. (Warning, hack ahead). So for strings:

```
String.prototype.meta = {};
String.prototype.addMeta = function(name, val) { this.meta[name] = val; }
String.prototype.getMeta = function(name) { return this.meta[name]; };
var str = 'some string value';
str.addMeta('meta', 'val');
alert(str.getMeta('meta'));
```

However this is clearly not ideal. For one thing, if the string was collected or aliased (since simple data types are copied by value, not reference) you would lose this meta. Only the first approach has any mileage in a real-world environment, to be honest.

Comment: That is bizarre, and intriguing. Is the non-enumerability the specified behaviour, or just a consequence of browser support?

Comment: No it's by design, part of the new object properties spec in ECMA5. It is possible to stipulate that properties *should* be enumerable, but by default they're not. I did [an extensive blog on this](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Feb/ECMAScript-revolution-object-properties-201) some time ago that might help.

Comment: Great - thanks for the clarification. I learned something new today!

Comment: +1 Great it's in ECMA. Checked it in node - works. As you mentioned, does not work for strings. Well, the separate meta object is I think like the map I mentioned in the question that I'm trying to avoid. When do you clean up?

Comment: In addition to suffer from the *needs manual garbage collection* problem, the second approach attaches metadata to **values**, not to **instances**. So I could not attach metadata to two different string instances, that happen to have the same characters, **independently** of each other.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't ideal - I was just thinking out loud for a non-ECMA5 fallback. See edit - you could take the prototype route, but it's a bit hacky.

Comment: @Utkanos Great that monkeypatching works with strings, too. Still, iinm `String.prototype` is *static*, so when a string instance gets collected, the value in `String.prototype.meta` remains there, right?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy - correct. As I say, the second approach is far from ideal and it's really only the first approach that is viable. But it's for object properties only, not simple data types.

Comment: What happens when such a meta'd object gets `JSON.stringify`'d?

Comment: @Utkanos Accepting your answer, it's the one that comes closest to what I want and it runs in node and ES5.

Comment: Updated blog link: https://web.archive.org/web/20130306030546/http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Feb/ECMAScript-revolution-object-properties-201

Answer (score 8):

ES6 spec introduces Map and WeakMap. You can enable these in node by running `node --harmony` and by enabling the experimental javascript flag in Chrome, (it's also in Firefox by default). Maps and WeakMaps allow objects to be used as keys which can be be used to store metadata about objects that isn't visible to anyone without access to the specific map/weakmap. This is a pattern I now use a lot:

```
function createStorage(creator){
  creator = creator || Object.create.bind(null, null, {});
  var map = new Map;
  return function storage(o, v){
    if (1 in arguments) {
      map.set(o, v);
    } else {
      v = map.get(o);
      if (v == null) {
        v = creator(o);
        map.set(o, v);
      }
    }
    return v;
  };
}
```

Use is simple and powerful:

```
var _ = createStorage();

_(someObject).meta= 'secret';
_(5).meta = [5];
var five = new Number(5);
_(five).meta = 'five';

console.log(_(someObject).name);
console.log(_(5).meta);
console.log(_(five).meta);
```

It also facilitates some interesting uses for separating implementation from interface:

```
var _ = createStorage(function(o){ return new Backing(o) });

function Backing(o){
  this.facade = o;
}
Backing.prototype.doesStuff = function(){
  return 'real value';
}

function Facade(){
  _(this);
}
Facade.prototype.doSomething = function doSomething(){
  return _(this).doesStuff();
}
```

Comment: Interesting stuff. Thanks for pointing me to ES6, didn't know about its existence. Looking at the current draft of the spec, the words `WeakMap` or even just `weak` aren't in there. Does this tell us something about the odds of WeakMaps being included in ES6 or why is it not in there.

Comment: This too can only be used with objects, not with strings. So the main difference between *Utkanos*' suggestion and `WeakMap`s would be that WeakMaps allow you to prevent others from seeing and modifying the metadata.

Comment: A WeakMap requires the keys be objects but a Map does not. In my code above you simply change WeakMap to Map and get the desired result. As far as inclusion in ES6, it certainly will be but for some reason just isn't in the spec yet. It's already implemented in V8 and Spidermonkey, one of the first ES6 features to be implemented. You can find it on http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proposals which lists accepted ES6 proposals. http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:simple_maps_and_sets http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:weak_maps

Comment: I updated my answer to use a Map which means it will work with both primitives and objects.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The problem with Map though is that you have to manually garbage collect, something that I cannot do (objects cross module boundaries, reference counting would be impractical to impossible). Unless I implement something that approximates that behavior without having to really track usage of objects/strings, something like LRU.

Comment: What you're asking for is kind of impossible then. You want to be able to use a primitive as a key (which means anyone at any time can have a reference to it) but have the result be garbage collected, which relies on references. In JavaScript the garbage collector is never observable. That is: if there could ever possibly be a reference to something then it should not and will not be garbage collected. Therefore something that uses primitives as keys can't be garbage collected. Objects have a unique identity and therefore can be refcounted and allow garbage collection. Pick your poison.

Comment: Clarification: if an object is reachable then it should not and will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Agree completely, it's impossible with primitives, which is why I  edited my question to only ask for `String`s. Unless JS interns every string (which I doubt, but haven't checked), it would be theoretically possible to either attach metadata to that instance or put it in some kind of weak map. But it does not seem to work with `String` and `WeakMap`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "comment" system in JSON. The best you can hope for is to add a property with an unlikely name, and add that key contaning the metadata. You can then read the metadata back out if you know it's metadata, but other setups will just see it as another property. And if someone uses `for..in`...

Comment: +1, though u may not find this answer useful to ur specific case, it's still a relevant addition to the discussion

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the Metadata as a "private" variable!?

```
var Obj = function (meta) {
    var meta = meta;
    this.getMetaData = function (key) {
        //do something with the meta object
        return meta;
    };
};
var ins_ob = new Obj({meta:'meta'});
var ins_ob2 = new Obj();
if(JSON.stringify(ins_ob) === JSON.stringify(ins_ob2)) {
    console.log('hoorai');
};
```

Comment: Something like `adding a closure that closes over a private variable to an object`. The problem with this is that the function `getMetaData` is enumerable and although `JSON.stringify` does not serialize it, it will turn up in a `for (var k in ins_ob)` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want object-level metadata, you could create a class that extends Object. Getters and setters are not enumerable and, obviously, neither are private fields.

```js
class MetadataObject extends Object {
  #metadata = undefined;
  
  get metadata() { return this.#metadata; }
  set metadata(value) { this.#metadata; }
}

var obj = new MetadataObject();
obj.a = 1;
obj.b = 2;
obj.metadata = { test: 123 };

console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
console.log(obj.metadata); // { test: 123 }
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // '{"a":1,"b":2}'
```

You can even simplify the implementation using a Map. Without a setter on `metadata`, you have to use Map methods to modify it.

```js
class MetadataObject extends Object {
  #metadata = new Map();
  
  get metadata() { return this.#metadata; }
}

var obj = new MetadataObject();
obj.a = 1;
obj.b = 2;
obj.metadata.set('test', 123);

console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
console.log(obj.metadata.get('test')); // 123
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // '{"a":1,"b":2}'
```

I ran into a situation where I needed property level metadata, and used the latter implementation.

```js
obj.id = 1;
obj.metadata.set('id', 'metadata for the id property');
```