# Store metadata in any value

Tags: javascript

So, I have different kinds of values in an object. These values were set using `Object.defineProperty()`. For now, assume the following example:

```js
let fooValue = 1;
let barValue = 'bar';

const obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
    get: () => fooValue,
    set: newValue => fooValue = newValue,
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'bar', {
    get: () => barValue,
    set: newValue => barValue = newValue,
});
```

Now I want to be able to pass these Values to a function and then be able to identify which value it is. I would hope to define something like a descriminator value:

```js
function test(val) {
    if(val.descriminator === 'foo')
        console.log('foo');
    else if(val.descriminator === 'bar')
        console.log('bar');
}

test(obj.foo); // print foo
test(obj.bar); // print bar
```

In pseudoish code, I want to be able to do this:

```js
const obj = {};

obj.foo = 1;
obj.foo.descriminator = 'foo';

obj.bar = 1;
obj.bar.descriminator = 'bar';
```

I am aware that that code does not work (`TypeError` in strict mode). I am also aware that I am well outside the bounds of how things are usually done.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11741019/9038475) to a similar question has an interesting idea (after edit): Adding metadata to the data type's prototype.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has wrapper classes for primitives like strings and numbers. You can wrap plain values in setters of your `obj` and add metadata using `defineProperty`.

```js
let fooValue;
let barValue;
    
const obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
    get: () => fooValue,
    set: newValue => fooValue = Object.defineProperty(
      new Number(newValue), 
      'descriminator', 
      {value: 'foo'}
    ),
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'bar', {
    get: () => barValue,
    set: newValue => barValue = Object.defineProperty(
      new String(newValue), 
      'descriminator', 
      {value: 'bar'}
    ),
});

obj.foo = 1;
obj.bar = 'bar';    

function test(val) {
    if(val.descriminator === 'foo')
        console.log('meta:foo', 'value:'+val);
    else if(val.descriminator === 'bar')
        console.log('meta:bar', 'value:'+val);
}

test(obj.foo);
test(obj.bar);
```

In most cases the wrapper classes of primitives may be used interchangeably with primitives. The `.valueOf()` for them will return raw primitive value, so they may be used in expressions, and compiler will extract their primitive value to make the calculations. One of the side effects, however, that you should be aware of is that `typeof obj.foo` will be `object` instead of `number`.

You can extend this method with smart setters that will detect the type of value to be set and use correct wrapper constructor. Or just define your own generic wrapper class like

```js
class Wrapper {
  #rawValue = undefined
  constructor(rawValue) {
    this.#rawValue = rawValue; 
  }
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    return {
      'string': String(this.#rawValue),
      'number': Number(this.#rawValue),
      'default': this.#rawValue
    }[hint]
  }
  valueOf() { return this.#rawValue; }
}
    
let obj = new class {
    #fooValue = undefined
    #barValue = undefined
    get foo() { return this.#fooValue; }
    set foo(val) { this.#fooValue = new Wrapper(val); }
    get bar() { return this.#barValue; }
    set bar(val) { this.#barValue = new Wrapper(val); }
};

function test(val) {
    if(val.descriminator === 'foo')
        console.log('foo '+val);
    else if(val.descriminator === 'bar')
        console.log('bar '+val);
}

obj.foo = 1;
obj.foo.descriminator = 'foo';

obj.bar = 1;    
obj.bar.descriminator = 'bar';


test(obj.foo);
test(obj.bar);
```